# Laravel 5.3 $errors not appearing in Blade

Tags: php, laravel

now I am studying laravel.

I have a problem:
Blade, doesn't want to show the validator error.

I create request "ContactRequest":

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ContactRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'=>'required',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
   return [
        'name.required' => 'Er, you forgot your name!',
   ];
}
 }
```

Just set up the controller for the page.

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 use Validator;


class ContactController extends Controller
{

public function store(ContactRequest $request) {

    return view('default.contact',['title'=>'Contacts']);
}


public function show()
{
    return view('default.contact',['title'=>'Contacts']);
}

}
```

Just add the right providers in the property of `$ middleware`:

```
protected $middleware = [
         \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

Created 2 router:

```
Route::get('/contact',['uses'=>'Admin\ContactController@show','as'=>'contact']);
Route::post('/contact',['uses'=>'Admin\ContactController@store']);
```

(Tried to just combine them into a group of `middleware => web` (did not help))

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif

<div class="form-area">  
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('contact') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name') }}" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('email') }}" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('site') }}" id="site" name="site" placeholder="site">
      </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="text" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="140" rows="7">{{ old('text') }}</textarea>
                    <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>                    
                </div>

             <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</div>
```

But in the end, when the form is submitted, the error messages are not displayed. Please tell me what to do? Thank you.

Comment: I might be blind, where where do you call the validation?

Comment: In ContactRequest

Comment: I see authorize, I see rule definitions, I see messages, but I don't see validate calls anywhere

Comment: Laravel does this automatically. But it does not matter, I can call the check directly in the controller:

        if( $request->isMethod('post') ) {

            $messages = [
                'name.required' => 'Er, you forgot your name!',
            ];

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name' => 'required',
            ],$messages);

            if( $validator->fails() ) {
                dump($validator)
            }

        }

But the same mistake does not show

Comment: Are your routes under `web` middleware? If yes then try it by removing the middleware.

Comment: Yeap. I tried this

Comment: @J.Doe You must have disabled the Validator or having some simmilair issues. Try installing from the composer a brand new Laravel project and see if the validations work there

Answer (score 0):

if the validation fails, you can redirect with errors:

```
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'name'=>'required']); 
if($validator->fails())
{
    return redirect("/contact")->withErrors($validator);    
}
```

and then, in the view:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```